# How to merge a JSONB array of objects into a single object in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a JSONB column where each row contains an array of multiple objects.

`'[{"a": 1}, {"b": 2}, {"c": 0.5}]'::jsonb`

I want to merge all of them together into a single object:

`'{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 0.5}'::jsonb`

I have tried using `coalesce` to merge them without success. I've also been playing around with multiple other inbuilt functions from Postgres but can't seem to figure this one out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to unnest the array and then aggregate the key/values back into a single object:

```
select (select jsonb_object_agg(e.ky, e.val) 
        from jsonb_array_elements(t.the_column) as x(element)
          cross join jsonb_each(x.element) as e(ky,val))
from the_table t;
```

Note, that if the array contains duplicate keys, the "last one" will win in this case (because JSON doesn't allow duplicate keys)

With Postgres 12 or later this can be simplified a little bit:

```
select (select jsonb_object_agg(e.item ->> 'key', e.item -> 'value')
        from jsonb_path_query(t.the_column, '$[*].keyvalue()') as e(item))
from the_table t
```

Answer (score 1):

CTE solution:

```
WITH cte (
    each_json
) AS (
    SELECT
        jsonb_path_query('[{"a": 1}, {"b": 2}, {"c": 0.5}]'::jsonb, '$[*]')
),
cte1 AS (
    SELECT
        (jsonb_each(each_json)).*
    FROM
        cte
)
SELECT
    jsonb_object_agg(key, value)
FROM
    cte1;
```